# Center bootstrap carousel text vertically, weird issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Ok so I am running into a weird issue, I am using the second method in this quick trick to center my content vertically inside the bootstrap carousel:

http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

Now I got this working but the container I have my content in becomes fluid, so I have to use offsets to get the content within the area I want it, this causes all kinds of problems for me.

When I put my CSS class

`.center-vertically-right {
    display:        table-cell;
    text-align:     right;
    vertical-align: middle;
}`

in the child element, this no longer works. I also moved `display: table;` to the parent.

I have set up a [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bzVx5/) that demonstrates my issue:

**Slide 1:** `.center-vertically-right` class inside of child (no longer working)

**Slide 2:** demonstrates issue `.center-vertically-left` class inside of `.container` class causing layout to become fluid.

**Slide 3:** centers fluid layout with bootstrap offsets (not what  I want)

I've read every question related and still cant find a solution.

I spent all night last night trying different methods of centering vertically and it seems that this is the closest I can get with the display: table method. I have tried [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19070256/center-content-vertically-in-bootstrap3-carousel-with-flexbox) with no success also a couple of other common ones, nothing seems to be working I at this point I am considering altering the design but will probably still try to figure this one out for the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/MRWej/4/) (Slide 2) what you are looking for? I think you just need to put `.container` inside of `.center-vertically-right`.

Comment: Yes you are correct, I figured this out yesterday just forgot to post back. Such simple fix, was a little tired the other night! Thank you